# Applying a filter of unknown elements using array. Or hiding select records from user

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Using a split database, everyone gets a front end with a local table I use as a 'cart' like in online shopping.

I'm copying records to a local table from stock. I don't want the record I copied across to be allowed to be transferred over again making duplicates. I also don't want to delete the original record, just modify it.

So I want them to edit the records copy locally then hit a button that will update the record on the database back end. If they don't hit the button and close the front end, no changes are made. Assume the temp table is wiped on start up.

To stop duplicate records I want to hide select records from the particular user of the front end database only. So if the Access app crashes the record isn't hidden for all users.

Idea: What If I add a Stock_ID (hidden) field to the local table? Then I can poll the column and if any Stock_ID matches the ID of the record I want to copy a message box says Error, record already exists and cancels the record copy?

Comment: It's an inventory management system. I updated the question to make it clearer. If I have copied a particular record then I want that record hidden to the local front end user (not all users) as long as it exists in my local table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying you want to show the front end user only those `stock` records whose `Stock_ID` values are not present in the `local` table.

If that is correct, you can use an "unmatched query" to display those `stock` records.

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM
    stock AS s
    LEFT JOIN [local] AS l
    ON s.Stock_ID = l.Stock_ID
WHERE l.Stock_ID Is Null;
```

The Access query designer has a query wizard for this task. It should be worth a look.

Comment: That would be perfect yes. I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Meanwhile I'm wondering whether you have a strategy which prevents 2 or more users from downloading and editing the same stock record.  Or is it not a concern if they might over-write each other's changes?

Comment: That worked perfectly I can't believe your solution was so simple. I was working on this for days. I'll be learning all the SQL commands now as it's obvious not everything can or even should be done via VBA.

Comment: For multiple users I'm polling the stock right before the update query to make sure there's still enough stock available. The only way something could go wrong (I presume) is if both users queries reached the backend at exactly the same time (instead of a few seconds apart).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "hide select records", what combinations? Hide all of a certain type from ALL users; hide certain records from SOME users? In your split database, does EACH user have a copy of the front-end, or do all share the same front-end? There must be some criteria that determines who sees what records? Once that is identified, then a solution can follow.

Comment: Each user has a copy of the front end. The record needs to be hidden for the local user only so they don't copy the same record twice. Think of it as a shopping cart system. You can see the record, edit the qty but no changes are made until you hit 'buy' then the database is updated.